# Cannot install pip on windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip

I downloaded [this](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/python-3.6.5-embed-amd64.zip) zip file from [python 3.6.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/) site and unzipped it to `c:\devel\opt\python`.

Added it to the path and followed [these](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/) instructions to install pip. Also tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/47633) answer at so.

So, this is what I have so far:

```
C:\>echo %PYTHON_HOME%
c:\devel\opt\python

C:\>echo %PATH%
[...]c:\devel\opt\python;c:\devel\opt\python\Scripts;[...]

C:\>python --version
Python 3.6.5

C:\>cd \devel\opt\pip

C:\devel\opt\pip>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
[...]
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed pip-10.0.1 setuptools-39.2.0 wheel-0.31.1


C:\devel\opt\pip>cd \devel\opt\python\Scripts

C:\devel\opt\python\Scripts>dir
[...]
19/06/2018  01:18 a.m.           102.751 pip.exe
19/06/2018  01:18 a.m.           102.751 pip3.6.exe
19/06/2018  01:18 a.m.           102.751 pip3.exe
19/06/2018  01:18 a.m.           102.748 wheel.exe
[...]

C:\devel\opt\python\Scripts>pip freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\devel\opt\python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

C:\devel\opt\python\Scripts>python -m pip freeze
c:\devel\opt\python\python.exe: No module named pip
```

I'm running windows 7 enterprise, SP 1

Any idea what could I be missing?

Comment: As the python version is 3.x execute the command using python3 as `python3 get-pip.py`

Comment: there's no python3.exe anywhere, only a python3.dll, python3 not recognized as a command...

Comment: after spending number of hours trying to make different things work in windows + python. I have found Anaconda to be the best option to be used in Windows. if it works for you I would suggest to use Anaconda.

Answer (score 3):

I did a little more research and it seems like pip is not supported on the [embedded distribution](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution):

> Third-party packages should be installed by the application installer
>   alongside the embedded distribution. Using pip to manage dependencies
>   as for a regular Python installation is not supported with this
>   distribution, though with some care it may be possible to include and
>   use pip for automatic updates.

Comment: Thanks for the info, sailing in the same boat as you. I tried the [detailed instructions here](http://www.clemens-sielaff.com/create-a-portable-python-with-pip-on-windows/) after getting the embedded distribution, but ended up with the same error as yours. Looks like regular installation is the only way if you want pip.

Comment: pip is for installing packages so the end goal of pip would be to add packages to the embedded distro. [This work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737721/adding-packages-to-python-embedded-installation-for-windows) worked for me, I used git on the Not Embedded Python Dir to track changes after "pip" installations.